# OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application in python

Tags: python, winapi, openpyxl

I am trying to run this code. I have added the transactions.xlsx to the project. I am getting this error

> OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

I've checked some older posts and it is mentioned that this might have to do with my PyCharm being 64bits. I did install openpyxl and it is in my external libraries. Any hints will be greatly appreciated. I am really new to Python.

```
 import openpyxl as xlm
 wb = xlm.load_workbook('transactions.xlsx')
 sheet = wb['Sheet1']
 cell = sheet['a1']
 cell = sheet.cell(1, 1)
 print(cell.value)
```

Comment: Presumably, openpyxl uses Excel's automation interfaces. If you are running this from a 64-bit application you also need to have the 64-bit version of Excel installed.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what was causing the issue. What I did was uninstall PyCharm and reinstalled it. Issue was solved.

Comment: If this solution did help you, please remember to mark it as answer to help people with the same issue.